# Bash: Store the last word of each line starting with

Tags: bash, grep, monitoring

I have a *.dat file that incrementally grows for several hours. I want to monitor a certain value in time so that I can compare them, watch its trend and so on.

What I have so far:

```
LTIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)

while true    
do
   ATIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then    
       grep "15 RT" test2.dat > test_grep2.txt
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 60
done
```

which updates an artificial textfile with each increment of the *.dat. Returns stuff like:

```
         15 RT    0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000     -1.4666E+04
         15 RT    0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000     -1.7073E+04
         15 RT    0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000     -1.9379E+04
         15 RT    0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000     -2.1583E+04
```

I also have this one:

```
while read line
do [ -z "$line" ] && continue ;echo ${line##* }
done < test_grep2.txt
```

which takes the last "word" of each line of such txt into the console:

```
1.0225E+04
1.1738E+04
1.3219E+04
1.4668E+04
1.6083E+04
2.4867E+04
2.5943E+04
```

But I havent succeeded yet in putting these two together. This just doesnt work (the last "words" are not printed out as the grep txt keeps getting updated):

```
[ -e test_grep.txt ] && rm test_grep.txt

LTIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)

while true    
do
   ATIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then
    grep -i "15 RT" test.dat > test_grep.txt

    LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 5
done

datime=$(stat -c %Z test_grep.txt)


while true    
do
   datime2=$(stat -c %Z test_grep.txt)

   if [[ "$datime2" != "$datime" ]]
   then
        while read line 

    do [ -z "$line" ] && continue ;echo ${line##* }
    done < test_grep.txt  


    datime=$datime2
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

And I believe that there must be a more efficient and elegant way that using a temp-file.

May I ask for your help with these? Sourcing the last "word" of each line that contains the string "15 RT" and either storing them or saving to a file for later comparison/evaluation. And all this "online". As the *.dat grows on and on.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reduce the problem.

Comment: Good point, thanks... Althoug a bit useless.

Comment: It is very useful, because it raises the chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should do it:

```
tail -f growing.dat | awk '/15 RT/ {print $NF}'
```

`tail -f` is very efficient, as it listens for file modify event and only outputs new lines when added (no need to loop and constantly check if file was modified). `awk` script will simply output the last field for each line that contains `15 RT`.

**Edit**. Additionally, if you wish to store that output to a file, and monitor the values in terminal, you can use `tee`:

```
tail -f growing.dat | awk '/15 RT/ {print $NF}' | tee values.log
```

Since `awk` is buffering output, to see the values in real-time, you can flush the output after each update:

```
tail -f growing.dat | awk '/15 RT/ {print $NF; fflush()}' | tee values.log
```

**Edit 2**. If the file doesn't exist initially, you should use `tail -F`:

```
tail -F growing.dat | awk '/15 RT/ {print $NF}'
```

that way, `tail` will keep retrying to open file if it is inaccessible, it looks like this (message is printed to `stderr`):

```
tail: cannot open 'growing.dat' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: 'growing.dat' has appeared;  following new file
-5.1583E+04
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes it a lot simpler! Can the stuff obtained in this way be stored to a list (for example) or a file for that further (still online) processing? Thank you!

Comment: Now it is almost perfect. The *.dat just must be present already. Lets assume it wont as it gets created later. When just watching, I usually use while ! tail -f muj_soubor.sta ; do sleep 1 ; done but cannot imagine how to accompany that in this case. May I ask for a very last hint? Thanks!

Comment: OK, got it. : ) while ! tail -f test2.dat ; do sleep 1 ; done | awk '/15 RT/ {print $NF; fflush()}' | tee values.log

Comment: As soon as the *.dat appears, the console says tail: 
tail: `test2.dat' has been replaced with a remote file. giving up on this name

Comment: I cannot reproduce that message. I've tried deleting/creating/overwriting, it always works. Can you write the exact scenario you have, so I can reproduce it? Or, better yet, create a new question; since this is definitely out of scope for this question.